# access permissions in ubuntu while creating app using yii framework

Tags: ubuntu, yii, dreamweaver, file-permissions, user-permissions

I've started to study yii framework.
Prepared ftp, all files are in place.
when I enter console comand to create app, it creates it, folders, files, but everything has root owner and it's all locked. So I cannot make new files in that folders with my Dreamweaver.

Shall I manually change rights from ubuntu console to each folder and file? or is there any other way to create new app with YII framework console command which creates folder structure under different user.

Or otherwise what's the right way to do it ?

I have root user, I have main user under which I log on to system, and I have ftp user under which I connect to system from different computer with Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute:

```
sudo chmod -R 644 /{project_folder}
```

For example:

```
sudo chmod -R 644 /var/www/my_project
```

Comment: I would say something like: less rights - more security. But on local computer you can do everything you like, including sudo chmod -R 755 /{project_folder} :)

Comment: If you use 644 in extensions folder you don't have permisions to use extension. I use 755 and i can use extensions